# Zbar vs zxing vs Google barcode api

Tags: android, zxing, android-vision

I'm developing android application for qr code scanner , I tried both Google android barcode API and zxing , but still confused which is better to use , and I have to develope one more application to generate barcode , is there any other library than zxing for generations of Qr code.
One app will generate qr code and other app will scan it.
Is it beter if I use zxing for both app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally use ZXing library for both tasks, I recently was able to successfully implement a simple Qr-Code scanning and generating app quite easily.

Let me know if you need any help with the implementation.

Comment: Thanks , Any reference you can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For generating a Qr code this is the tutorial I found similar to mine and 100% working : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vWHbCr_OWM ...for developing the scanner http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162 or https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-qr-code-scanner-using-zxingscanner-library-tutorial/  I'm not sure how these 2 resources would   turn out to be but hit me up if you get any errors in development.

Comment: If you are thinking of long term support I would recommend Google Barcode Api. As we have seen google keeps introducing APIs that eventually will replace 3rd party API's. For example Robotium getting replaced with Google's Expresso testing framework.

Comment: @TerNovi Your assumption is valid, but may I point out that ZXing is a Google project way back in 2007, and is still receiving regular updates. Google Barcode Api is just as fast and accurate as the ZXing library but has a long way to go.

Comment: @RamithDR Can you send me sample code for Both generating and scanning bar code , actually I am new to android